# Dropbox API: Get Name of user who Last Modified a Shared File

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm working on a 3rd party tool that integrates the Dropbox API and I would like to be able to display the name of the user who last modified the file.

The API documentation doesn't seem to supply this information, but I just want to verify that I'm not overlooking anything.

Anyone have experience with this area of the Dropbox API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can verify that this is not currently exposed via the API.